# Unable to Produce JSON - javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException

Tags: json, rest, maven, jersey

Am using Jersey 1.15, JDK 1.6, Tomcat 7, Maven 2.2.1 to create a simple Restful Web Service that should return a JSON String from a POJO that I mapped.

Here's my pojo:

```
package com.myservice.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

  // Getters & Setters
}
```

my webservice:

```
package com.myservice.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.myservice.domain.Person;

@Path("/service")
public class MyService {

    @GET
    @Path("showPerson")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getPerson() {
       Person person = new Person();
       person.setFirstName("John");
       person.setLastName("Doe");
       return person;
    }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
         <groupId>com.myservice</groupId>
         <artifactId>myservice</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <packaging>war</packaging>
         <name>My Web Service</name>

         <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>junit</groupId>
                 <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                 <version>4.8.2</version>
                 <scope>test</scope>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>1.15</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
             </dependency>

            <dependency>
               <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
               <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
               <version>1.15</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                  <version>1.15</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                 <version>1.14</version>
            </dependency>

           <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>1.14</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
               <version>1.9.9</version>
           </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
          <finalName>myservice</finalName>
          <plugins>
                <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                       <source>1.6</source>
                       <target>1.6</target>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>
          </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"
         metadata-complete="true">
     <display-name>My Web Service</display-name>
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myservice.resource</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After deploying to tomcat, when I try to invoke the web service like this:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/myservice/rest/service/showPerson
```

I get the following error:

```
Nov 20, 2012 10:40:06 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class com.myservice.domain.Person, 
and Java type class com.myservice.domain.Person, 
and MIME media type application/json was not found

Nov 20, 2012 10:40:06 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class com.myservice.domain.Person,
and Java type class com.myservice.domain.Person, and MIME media type 
application/json was not found

Nov 20, 2012 10:40:06 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write 
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the 
MIME media type are: */* ->

     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProviderfg
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General

    Nov 20, 2012 10:40:06 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse 
    write

      SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the 
      MIME media type are:
      */* ->

     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General

    SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)

    javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: 
    com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException:

    A message body writer for Java class
    com.myservice.domain.Person, 
    and Java type class com.myservice.domain.Person, 
    and MIME media type application/json was not found

    com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: 

    A message body writer for Java class com.myservice.domain.Person, 
    and Java type class com.myservice.domain.Person, and MIME media type  
    application/json was not found

    HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error 
    The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from 
    fulfilling this request.
```

After scouring the Internet, I tried inserting the following proposed solution that everyone suggested into web.xml:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But it still gives me the same issue! It does return the correct data marshalled to XML if I use APPLICATION_XML, however.

Would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) library in your dependencies.
It will automatically enable JSON-POJO databinding.

Comment: Yes, that actually worked! Why is this? Thank you very much you are such a lifesaver!

Comment: Should I be using genson, jackson, or jersey-json for my parsing?

Comment: I am gensons author so I would ofcorse recommend genson ;-) but Jackson would work also. The main advantge of genson over Jackson is ease of use, design with extension in mind, all in one small jar size but powerfull , there are other things but more technical

Comment: @TOUDIdel I dont know what your problem is, you should start a new question and post the link here. To get help with genson you can also use its user group.

Comment: @socal_javaguy Could you please have a look this problem, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420733/jersey-json-mapping-with-java-lang-nullpointerexception-unable-to-produce-json

Comment: This worked for me too. Using jersey-json and jackson-mapper-asl did not :(

Answer (score 1):

Add jersey-json to your dependencies. It will add a JSON serialization implementation.

Add this to `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, which is a shame because I prefer this to the other solution.