# Jersey Json mapping with java.lang.NullPointerException, Unable to Produce JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jersey

I have a domain class with @XMLRootElement annotation which will be return from the service.

My service is something like:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/GetProductList")
public Response getProductList(@QueryParam("Username") String username,
                             @QueryParam("Password") String password) {

        CategoryResponse result = new CategoryResponse(returnDummyCategories());

        return Response.ok().entity(result).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error fetching products.", e);
        throw new WebApplicationException(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Also I have put the init parameter in the web.xml file:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
```

As well I put the the code

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>0.97</version>
</dependency>
```

in the pom.xml file.

But I still get exception following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.<init>(ContainerRequest.java:188)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createRequest(WebComponent.java:446)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:380)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter.doFilter(ServletDispatchingFilter.java:123)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:67)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:70)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:58)
info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:66)
info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:153)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:76)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:84)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:60)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:86)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.module.templatingkit.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:97)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:75)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:93)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.enterprise.registration.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:52)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.UnicodeNormalizationFilter.doFilter(UnicodeNormalizationFilter.java:90)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.module.devicedetection.filter.DeviceDetectionFilter.doFilter(DeviceDetectionFilter.java:73)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:102)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:131)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:67)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:108)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:108)
info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:94)
```

Can't find something wrong with the code and configuration.

Comment: this happens when you deploy your application to server, or while making a request to above endpoint ?

Comment: Did you add the jersey module for json support? I can't see it in your pom.

Comment: @benjiman genson is the same as json support for jersey. Even is replace with json, still have the same problem. thanks.

Comment: @Sikorski Yes, that's correct. I can make sure the request works if there is no object/json added. Got some idea?

Comment: @ttt do you mean that when you don't give body in request, this exception doesn't come ?  Please update your question with inputs for is it deployment time issue or does it happen while making request. And also some scenarios when it fails and when it doesn't.

Comment: @Sikorski I switched the restful implementation to resteasy and everything works. Code didn't change just some configurations.

Comment: though changing framework serves the purpose but doesn't solves the original problem. I have built a couple of JSON Restful Services with jersey and it didnt gave my any problems.