# WebApplicationException in JSON using

Tags: java, json, rest, maven

I've searching about this problem that occurred when using JSON and RESTful example but i couldn't found anything.
here is my code:

```
@Path("students")
public class StudentResource {
private StudentRepository studentRepository = new StudentRepositoryStub();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Student> getallStudentList() {
    return studentRepository.findAllStudents();
}

}
```

and here is web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>untitled67</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and at last this is student class :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Student {
private String name;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

that the student class is filling with :

```
public class StudentRepositoryStub implements StudentRepository {

public List<Student> findAllStudents() {
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("jamshid");
    student.setAge(22);

    studentList.add(student);

    student.setName("saeid");
    student.setAge(26);
    studentList.add(student);

    return studentList;

}
}
```

when i using

> MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

instead of

> MediaType.APPLICATION_XML

this error occured:

> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:267)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1035)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:947)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:938)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:478)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:663)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and i dont know why! it just work as XML! please help me tnx.

Comment: Please post the full error log - there should be a "Caused by" line, at least, and also a **SEVERE** line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Produce JSON - javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482346/unable-to-produce-json-javax-ws-rs-webapplicationexception-com-sun-jersey-api)

Comment: ive sent the full error it dosn't have any 'cause by' !

Answer (score 3):

there are two changes which u need to do is

1. change the @Produces("application/json")
2. Always the path should begin from @Path("/students")
3. add dependency

   `<dependency>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
           <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.0</version>
       </dependency>`

read the docs for more detailed information: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html

Comment: ive added  ur dependency in POM and change Produce and Path but it has previous exception.

Comment: somewhere in the logs you must be getting this issue "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException". To solve this prob you may have to add "org.eclipse.persistence.moxy" dependency

Comment: by adding this dependency i've got a new error:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter
and
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri